# How to change the button text when take picture using cordova-plugin-camera

Tags: cordova, camera

When I take a picture by using cordova-plugin-camera,there is a picutre and two buttons in the bottom.The text on the buttons is "Retake" and "Use Photo".

So I want to change the text on the buttons,is any way to try?

Thanks.